# Google Storage access from Android with nonservice account - 403 Forbidden/Access Not Configured

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-cloud-storage

This has been a massively frustrating experience. I am trying to access Google Cloud Storage (list a bucket accessibe to anyone) and do it from Android via a **nonservice** account.

Here is my code:

```
    import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
    import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
    import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
    import com.google.api.client.http.InputStreamContent;
    import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
    import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
    import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
    import com.google.api.services.storage.Storage;
    import com.google.api.services.storage.model.Bucket;
    import com.google.api.services.storage.model.StorageObject;

    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

    Credential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setClientSecrets("ANDROID_CLIENT_ID_FROM_DEV_CONSOLE", "some random string, since no clienet secret for android")
            .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .build();
    credential.setAccessToken(token);

    Storage storage = new Storage.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory,
            credential)
            .setApplicationName("My app name")
            .build();
    List<StorageObject> objects = storage.objects().list("my-bucket").execute().getItems()
```

Considerations:

- I get a valid oauth token which has the following scopes:
  "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write"
- I have Google Cloud Storage JSON API and Google Cloud Storage enabled in the API section of my Cloud Dev Console.
- As an alternative, I tried setting it up with a serivce account (i.e. using methods like setServiceAccountId(...) when creating a GoogleCredential) and it works perfectly. But i want this to work on behalf of an authorized user, as per above code snippet!
- All of my code is in package com.mytestapp.  This is the package i specified when creating the Android client id.
- I am launching the app through a debugger in Android Studio, while the app is launched on my physical Android device.

Problem Statement:

During executing the list bucket operation above, i get this Json exception:

**com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "usageLimits",
    "message" : "Access Not Configured. The API (Cloud Storage API) is not enabled for your project. ............}**

What am i doing wrong? Is it because i am not setting up the client secret right? (i thought no client secrets for Android anymore). Or application name has to be smth very specific? I set it to some free-form text string.

I thought this was supposed to be easy and straightforward!

At the very least -- is there a coherent, complete example of how to do this for **nonservice** accounts on Android? I searched all over the place without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it. The SHA1 signature of the app was wrong. Hence, a mismatch of credentials between it and Google.